# Estou tento mover arquivos zerados(sem conteúdo 0kb), preciso de ajuda!

Tags: c#

Ao apertar o botão preciso mover todos os arquivos zerados de um diretório para outro.

Meu código.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            
var pasta = (@"C:\Users\Desktop\Nova pasta\");


var pasta2 = (@"C:\Users\Desktop\Nova pasta\outro\");

  var dir = new DirectoryInfo(pasta);
            
   foreach (FileInfo arquiv in dir.GetFiles()){

   if (arquiv.Length <= 0)
                    
{
  arquiv.MoveTo(pasta2);

                 }
             }
                
         }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você utilizará:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Primeiro você precisa checar os arquivos existentes na pasta, algo como

```
var arquivos = Directory.EnumerateFiles(pasta).ToArray();
```

conseguirá fazer isso para você.

Após, terá que pegar somente o nome do arquivo (Regex pode te ajudar nisso).

Em seguida você pode utilizar uma condicional dentro de um loop como:

```
foreach(var arquivo in arquivos)
    if (new FileInfo(arquivo).Length < 1)
    {
        File.Move(arquivo, pasta2 + arquivo);
    }
```

Com isso você vai conseguir comparar o tamanho do arquivo, como está num loop, a cada laço a comparação será realizada com o arquivo correspondente à posição do loop e caso atenda suas condições, movido.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, isso me ajudou muito.